# How can I get an RSS feed of just my own questions?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, feed

I would like an RSS feed that shows each question I ask (but not comments or other cruft)

This is for StackOverflow to twitter integration.  I've set up twitterfeed to import my user feed into twitter ([see here](http://twitter.com/mistersql))

For questions this works nicely.  It is entirely possible my question fits in 140 characters and my followers might want be able to answer.

However, my followers don't give a hoot about me leaving a comment on some random person's question.  Is there a pre-existing feed to filter out the cruft from my user feed?

Comment: Wow, I must have been asleep when I retagged this question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you're looking for:

> `http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/{site}/users/{ID}/questions?body=true`
>
> For example, Jeff Atwood's questions:
>
> http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/1/questions?body=true

It's a small app I wrote called [Stack2RSS](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service) that converts API requests to RSS feeds.

Comment: Well, *small app*, Jeff likes it so much that [he wrote earlier](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62588/rss-overhaul-desperately-needed/104673#104673): *"we are directly supporting Nathan's (awesome) Stack2RSS [...] In that we are providing server space and bandwidth for it on our own servers. So please make use of that if possible."*

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked [libraries and apps](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps) that use the API to see if there is something that suits your purposes? I haven't had the time to look at these properly myself yet, but if I run across something that looks like it might be useful for you, I'll try to remember to mention it here.

Comment: There's one now. See my answer.