# Is there an RSS feed for all the questions I've asked on the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: discussion, questions, feed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get an RSS feed of just my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55868/how-can-i-get-an-rss-feed-of-just-my-own-questions)

I'd like to create an [ifttt.com](http://ifttt.com) recipe that takes all questions I ask on the SE network, and emails them to me. Is there a global RSS feed? Something else I could use for that?

Comment: Did [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55868/how-can-i-get-an-rss-feed-of-just-my-own-questions) question help?

Comment: @Marvin - actually, it's not a dup - the accepted answer to that question is a per-site feed ... I want a global one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no, there isn't.

A (very kludgey) workaround is you taking *all* of your user feeds across *all* of the Stack Exchange sites - the link to which is in the lower right hand corner of your profile, as seen here:

[image: User feed link]

And then aggregate them together using code or a service into one feed.

Note that if you are going to use a feed aggregator service, that [Yahoo Pipes is currently blocked from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23826/jeff-why-did-you-block-yahoo-pipes) (I'm not sure about the rest of the Stack Exchange sites, but I think it's safe to say that's the case) and others might be blacklisted depending on their behavior towards the site.